# Update clientId after initializing Google Actions SDK for NodeJS

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm using the account linking feature for Actions SDK and following the guide here (https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in#start_the_authentication_flow)

It shows the initialization like this

```
const app = actionssdk({
     // REPLACE THE PLACEHOLDER WITH THE CLIENT_ID OF YOUR ACTIONS PROJECT
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
});
```

But for my use case, I'll read the `clientId` from DB which is stored against the `projectId` of the project. I can extract the `projectId` only after the `MAIN` intent is triggered.

My question is, how can I set the `clientId` after initializing `actionssdk`?

Comment: Can you determine the project ID from the request URL?

Comment: Yes I can. I take the aud field after decoding the jwt token

Comment: In that case you could probably wait for initialize the app object until you're within the request handler.

Comment: I might have misunderstood your query. I can extract the projectId only after I have initialized the actionssdk and listening on the MAIN intent. But at this step I already had to initialize the actionssdk with a static clientId

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses the new Actions SDK, but the principal is the same for the legacy SDK as well:

```js
const {
  conversation,
  Canvas,
} = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');


const wrapper = async (req, res) => {
  // You can get any data you need here:
  const myAsyncBootstrapData = await getData();
  const app = conversation({debug: true, ...myAsyncBootstrapData});

  app.handle('welcome', (conv) => {
    conv.add('This is a demo.');
  });
  
  return app(req, res);
};

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(wrapper);
```

`functions.https.onRequest` accepts any callable, including ones that return promises. If you need to block while loading configuration data asynchronously, you can do so by wrapping your definition in an async function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found another approach that is close to your answer but I found it simpler to use.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to this. I am adding it here for future references.

```
// handler.js
async function handleRequest(req, res) {
    const clientId = // retrieve the clienId using your business logic
    const app = actionssdk({
        clientId: clientId
    })
}

module.exports = handleRequest;
```

Instead of directly creating an instance of `actionssdk`, wrap it inside a function like this.

```
// index.js
const handler = require('./path/to/hander.js');
app.post('/webhook', handler);
```

Then when defining the webhook, use the wrapper function to handle the webhook requests